# IBM Content Navigator on WebSphere does not apply the JavaScript changes made to widgets

Tags: dojo, websphere-7, ibm-content-navigator

Hey guys i am working with **WebSphere 7.0** and **IBM Content Navigator**.

I am trying to make some changes to the **.js (dojo)** files to modify a few features of ICN but any change i make does not apply to the application.

I guess that it does not identify the change because it's a .js file but **i tried Stopping WebSphere, then clean the "temp" directory of navigator and Start WebSphere again**.
Nothing changed! I added alerts to the code so i can be sure the change is noticeable but again nothing.

Do you have any suggestions as to how i can (easily) have the changes applied to the application?

If you need any more information please let me know!

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Solon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Content Navigator uses a compressed file, "ecm.js.jgz" containing all widget code. This is what is referred to and other JS are not used in run time.

Comment: Hey Siva, I figured that out but Thank you for your answer.